# sorting dynamically created table from html form elemets

Tags: javascript, forms, sorting, local-storage

sorry for my english.
I am new at this so i would appreciate a little help here,
I have a html form and its data is shown on my page in html table.
After each new saving form data table sorts by form entry id.

Now i am stuck with sorting and pagination
How can i sort this table data by clicking on column header for some other data, for example by `animal_id` or `animal_name.`

Thanks for your help

here is the code:

```
        init: function() {
                if (!Animals.index) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("Animals:index", Animals.index = 1);
            }
            Animals.$form.reset();
            Animals.$button_discard.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                Animals.$form.reset();
                Animals.$form.id_entry.value = 0;
            }, true);
            Animals.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                var entry = {
        id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                    animal_id:this.animal_id.value,
        animal_name: this.animal_name.value,
        animal_type: this.animal_type.value,
                    bday: this.bday.value,
                    animal_sex: this.animal_sex.value,
                    mother_name: this.mother_name.value,
                    farm_name: this.farm_name.value,
        money: this.money.value,
        weight: this.weight.value,
                    purchase_partner: this.purchase_partner.value,

                };
                if (entry.id == 0) { // add
                    Animals.storeAdd(entry);
                    Animals.tableAdd(entry);
                }
                else { // edit
                    Animals.storeEdit(entry);
                    Animals.tableEdit(entry);
                }

                this.reset();
                this.id_entry.value = 0;
                event.preventDefault();
            }, true);


            if (window.localStorage.length - 1) {
                var animals_list = [], i, key;
                for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
                    key = window.localStorage.key(i);
                    if (/Animals:\d+/.test(key)) {
                        animals_list.push(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)));
                    }
                }

                if (animals_list.length) {
                            animals_list.sort(function(a, b)
                            {return a.id < b.id ? -1 : (a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);
                                                           })

                        .forEach(Animals.tableAdd);

                                                } }


            Animals.$table.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                var op = event.target.getAttribute("data-op");
                if (/edit|remove/.test(op)) {
                    var entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("Animals:"+ event.target.getAttribute("data-id")));
                    if (op == "edit") {
            Animals.$form.id_entry.value = entry.id;
                        Animals.$form.animal_id.value = entry.animal_id;
            Animals.$form.animal_name.value = entry.animal_name;
                        Animals.$form.animal_type.value = entry.animal_type;
                        Animals.$form.bday.value = entry.bday;
                        Animals.$form.animal_sex.value = entry.animal_sex;
                        Animals.$form.mother_name.value = entry.mother_name;
            Animals.$form.farm_name.value = entry.farm_name;
                        Animals.$form.money.value = entry.money;
                        Animals.$form.weight.value = entry.weight;
                        Animals.$form.purchase_partner.value = entry.purchase_partner;

                    }
                    else if (op == "remove") {
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this animal from your list?' )) {
                            Animals.storeRemove(entry);
                            Animals.tableRemove(entry);
                        }
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }, true);
        },

        storeAdd: function(entry) {
            entry.id = Animals.index;
            window.localStorage.setItem("Animals:index",++Animals.index);
            window.localStorage.setItem("Animals:"+entry.id,JSON.stringify(entry));
        },
        storeEdit: function(entry) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("Animals:"+entry.id,JSON.stringify(entry));
        },
        storeRemove: function(entry) {
            window.localStorage.removeItem("Animals:"+ entry.id);
        },

        tableAdd: function(entry) {
            var $tr = document.createElement("tr"), $td, key;
            for (key in entry) {
                if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    $td = document.createElement("td");
                    $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
                    $tr.appendChild($td);
                }
            }
            $td = document.createElement("td");
            $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id+'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
            $tr.appendChild($td);
            $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);
            Animals.$table.appendChild($tr);
        },
        tableEdit: function(entry) {
        var $tr = document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id), $td, key;
            $tr.innerHTML = "";
            for (key in entry) {
                if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    $td = document.createElement("td");
                    $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
                    $tr.appendChild($td);
                }
            }
            $td = document.createElement("td");
            $td.innerHTML = '<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
            $tr.appendChild($td);
        },
        tableRemove: function(entry) {
            Animals.$table.removeChild(document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id));
        }
    };


    Animals.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your current approach is to have your code managing the Table HTML and the Animal data directly, it will need to be your code that does the sorting of the data and the rewrite of the table.  That is, you will need to listen for click events on the column headers, and then sort your Animal data according to that particular column, and then redraw the table completely.  Redrawing the table could simply entail looping through your tableRemove() and then tableAdd() functions for all Animals being displayed, although that might be a little slow.  The sorting of the data by each column is a bit more of a mess for which I have a solution below.

A better approach would be to allow a RIA (Rich Internet Application) Framework to handle the table information for you.  Many of these frameworks (EXT-JS, YUI, etc) provide a Table control that will simplify your coding dramatically.  You merely give it a reference to your data (formatted in a relevant format), and it will do the sorting and display for you.

If you still want to create the HTML Table yourself, and are more interested in the sorting of the data, then I would suggest going with a Client-side Database solution such as [SequelSphere](http://www.SequelSphere.com).  With SequelSphere, you could create a table to manage your Animal data, as follows:

```
db.catalog.createTable({
    tableName: "animals",
    columns: ["id_entry", "animal_id", "animal_name", "animal_type",
            "bday", "animal_sex", "mother_name", "farm_name", "money",
            "weight", "purchase_partner"],
    primaryKey: ["id_entry"]
});
```

Then you can Insert/Update/Delete rows like this:

```
db.catalog.getTable("animals").insertRow(
     [ entry.id, entry.animal_id, entry.animal_name, entry.animal_type,
     entry.bday, entry.animal_sex, entry.mother_name, entry.farm_name,
     entry.money, entry.weight, entry.purchase_partner ]
);
```

Finally, you can get your data Sorted by whatever column the user clicked by merely changing the ORDER BY clause in the following select statement:

```
var sql =   "SELECT id_entry, animal_id, animal_name, animal_type, " +
            "       bday, animal_sex, mother_name, farm_name, money, " +
            "       weight, purchase_partner " +
            "  FROM animals " +
            " ORDER BY animal_sex "; // why did I choose this column?
var sortedEntries = db.query(sql);
```

Oh yes: [SequelSphere](http://www.SequelSphere.com) also stores the data in window.localStorage, so you wouldn't have to write that either.  It also has full support for SQL and cursors, so managing the Pagination would be a bit easier as well.

Hope this helps!

john...